# Multithreaded stress tests fail

Tags: testing, service, stress-testing

I am doing a stress test of a web service by running many threads of the same process, but the second thread always stops in the middle of running without throwing an exception. How do you figure out what’s wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a debugger against it, and place breakpoints in logical places to see if you can figure out where it's breaking.